# How to find all recent posts and comments by SE staff?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-team, company

How might I review all staff posts and comments published since late September?

If that's not possible, then how about just the posts?

Comment: This is nowhere as streamlined as Glorfindel's answer but have you tried looking at their accounts and checking the activity tab? (All activity)

Comment: @curious it'd be rather tedious to check [all 248 of them](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1170430/accounts-of-stack-exchange-staff)

Comment: Related: [How to search for questions from ♦ users (moderators / employees)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315528/398063)

Answer (score 13):

It's hard enough already to [generate a list of staff members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331141/295232), but I guess you could use the API to get a list of [recent posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts) and [recent comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments) (those calls support pagination). For each new 100 user IDs you encounter, request the [complete user record](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids). Those contain an `is_employee` field, indicating whether a user is a staff member or not. This might be doable before running out of your [daily API quota](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) (10000 if you have a registered Stack App).

It's not possible to make a SEDE query for this, since whether a user is an employee or not isn't stored there. But, if you have a list of user IDs, it's doable.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1170783/posts-by-stack-exchange-staff?fromDate=2019-09-28) is a list of posts since September 28th:

[image]

and [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1170784/comments-by-stack-exchange-staff?fromDate=2019-09-28) a list of comments:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Can you think of a way to write a feature request?  If I'm interested in viewing your posts, I can click on your username, click on "Activity," and then choose "All."  The most recent items will show up first.  But for staff, we're talking about multiple users.  Would a collection of links to each staff post and comment have to be made manually?

Comment: Stack Exchange is about the *content*, not the *users*. That's probably why it isn't possible. Sure, here on Meta.SE staff posts carry more weight, but searching for staff posts isn't a frequently occurring use case, I guess.