# Show leaderboard for colleagues

Tags: support, users, reputation-leagues

Is it possible to show the [leaderboard](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) for a group of users, for example friends or colleagues using a list of user IDs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite easy to generate an all-time leaderboard using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). As an example, I have compiled a list of user IDs from Stack Exchange staff (via [this method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331141/295232)) and used that for a [Meta Stack Exchange leaderboard for this group](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1294845/all-time-leaderboard-for-a-group-of-users?UserIDs=3,4,51,91,5190,6212,23354,50049,130213,131257,139284,135201,141235,141525,146126,155160,156631,164200,165581,173432,175506,187267,193284,200773,202841,208517,208518,213659,213916,220750,222882,233415,235711,238712,238801,238921,242868,242956,248860,253117,253547,254686,259107,261314,262550,265649,265754,267421,267572,269744,274323,275592,278972,280328,282241,284336,285849,286963,287938,288412,289568,292464,292509,296470,296784,306119,306180,306181,308650,308664,309381,309382,309868,310174,310571,311079,312625,312743,312922,314762,314875,318071,318945,318951,318952,323037,325611,327819,328394,330582,335054,340078,340281,340282,342225,342786,344092,344828,348754,349208,349251,350924,352085,354392,355163,355481,358207,362644,364360,368280,369250,370877,371894,371930,371932,371941,373679,376728,379210,379213,380111,383293,384372,384467,386446,386975,386976,386977,387521,389304,389943,390399,390411,390413,392414,392464,393819,394111,394114,395497,398530,399529,400423,401062,401063,401322,401460,402517,403834,409959,409960,409964,410743,423506,430118,432335,440650,452001,453303,453304,453464,460639,485283,485365,493532,497552,498329,498833,502975,507720,508266,510771,512317,512881,516441,519992,519993,520046,523443,528105,531877,531878,534929,545299,558563,564417,564418,566698,566699,566700,576323,576461,579126,584503,589597,590098,593716,595342,597236,605701,605716,605965,605969,616040,616085,617305,652456,661133,661134,666372,666888,669812,682777,704608,713084,713085,713087,713088,713089,713090,713091,713092,713093,713094,713427,726273,728969,730623,736305,737401,737413,738349,748542,754060,766682,769510,775525,784098,784336,784338,784339,814785,789076,807466,807495,807496,807497,816947,821203,825530):

[image]

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning (but the leaderboards aren't real-time either). SEDE is worse at compiling weekly/monthly leaderboards, that requires complicated queries similar to [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1170724/reputation-graph).

Comment: This is great - Bonus Question: I guess it's not easily possible across multiple sites, because the user IDs differ, right?

Comment: Oh, that's certainly possible, because site accounts are connected via a network account with an ID you can find here: https://stackexchange.com/users/current. But due to association bonuses etc. simply taking the sum of the reputation isn't really meaningful.