# Where should I post something about Stack Exchange but not a question, such as a table of badge IDs?

Tags: support

I am currently working on a table that contains all the different Badge-IDs for all the different Stack Exchange sites. Where should I post things like that?

Comment: You could post a question such as "What are the different badge ids on the various sites?" and self-answer with the information

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing Should I then mark it as a wiki entry or do you think it's not appropriate?

Comment: @gurkensaas Only if you want or think it's useful; you don't _have_ to. See: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/348196) and [Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227290/348196). Note that self-answering is perfectly fine. The system even gives you the option to [post a question and answer it simultaneously in one action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400494/8967612).

Comment: That said, that sounds like the type of post that would benefit from being a community wiki. I just wanted to point out that just because it's a self-answered question, doesn't mean the answer has to be marked as community wiki.

Comment: You should consider that if there's over 350 columns (mains and metas) that hosting the file offsite at Google and Microsoft (and leaving it editable, with you retaining the ability to rollback vandalism) might be better than trying to stuff it all on one webpage. Another consideration is what is to be done with the information; should it be T-SQL compatible, or is Excel sufficient. --- Don't forget to tell us why we need the information, and suggestions to make use of it.

Comment: Thanks to all the comments, I've now concluded how I want to do this:
1. I am going to post a self-answered question on MSE which I am probably going to mark as Wiki.
2. I am going to post the table in as many formats as I possibly can on Github. Formats include .xslx, .db, .csv and .numbers. Posting it on Github while still allow users to make edits and suggestions and will also allow me to post the code I ran to get the tables.

Comment: You should also consider posting the method you obtained that data, so others can repeat it (should you decide to leave Stack Exchange, or not keep it up to date). Some of my own examples: [helpful flaggers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332733/295232), [site names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359795/295232), [staff members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331141/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel Do you mean posting the exact source code or posting the method?

Comment: I would post the exact source code, unless you don't want to distribute it under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing).

Comment: @Glorfindel I plan on posting the source code, the problem is, the method I'm using only works with macOS and with Google Chrome and Chromium-based browsers. I think I am going to post the source code in the wiki-post and write as much documentation as I possibly can.

Comment: Well, the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369665/is-there-a-table-of-badge-ids-for-all-stack-exchange-sites/) is out now.

Answer (score -1):

As [Dude coinheringaahing mentioned in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369125/where-should-i-post-something-about-stack-exchange-but-not-a-question-such-as-a#comment1231566_369125), one possible option would be to [self-answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/560258), and if you do that, you might want to mark the post(s) as CW depending on its content. In addition, the answer might benefit from a SEDE query so that it stays up to date (note: this might not be possible in SEDE)

Comment: I stated the specifications about that post. I do not exactly know what SEDE is, but for my script, I use mostly JavaScript to get the HTML and then processing it using Applescript.

Comment: @gurkensaas well then posting the JavaScript and AppleScript is an option, if you want to.

Comment: As stated above, that's what I plan on doing. I have already written most of the wiki entry and code. I'm currently fixing the last few bugs.

Comment: After going through SEDE, I think there would be a way to get the badge IDs for each site separately but not with all sites